# How to do a parallel computation on Python exactly specifying cpu no i do task i?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-3.7

Define the following function which adds natural numbers until where you ask.

```
def f(x):
    lo=0
    for i in range(x):
            lo+=i
    return(lo)
```

To parallel it using multiprocessing.dummy I wrote the following

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool=ThreadPool(4)
def f_parallel(x1,x2,x3,x4):
    listo_parallel=[x1,x2,x3,x4]
    resulto_parallel=pool.map(f,listo_parallel)
    return(resulto_parallel)
```

It works, but I don't see any reduction in time of computation. Because define the following functions which reports the computation time as well.

```
import time
def f_t(x):
    st=time.time()
    lob=f(x)
    st=time.time()-st
    return(lob,st)
def f_parallel_t(x1,x2,x3,x4):
    listo_parallel=[x1,x2,x3,x4]
    st=time.time()
    resulto_parallel=pool.map(f,listo_parallel)
    st=time.time()-st
    return(resulto_parallel,st)
```

Now let's examine. for x=10**7, 9**7, 10**7-2, 10**6 normal f takes 0.53, 0.24, 0.53, 0.04 seconds. And for four of them the f_parallel takes 1.39 seconds!!!!! I expected to see 0.53 seconds because the computer I used has 4 cpus and I chose 4 in the pool. But why it's going like this?

I also tried to read the documentation of the multiprocessing library of Python 3.7 but they works only if I type the examples exactly the way they are written there. For example consider the first example in that document. If I type

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
Pool(4).map(f,[10**7,9**7,10**7-2,10**6])
```

Then nothing happens and I have to restart shell (Ctrl+F6).

And doing this pool.map is not really what I want, I want to tell Python to do f(x_i) exactly on cpu no. i. So I want to know what part of my computation is being done on which cpu at any step of my programming.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

---

For the case someone doesn't get what I really want to do with python, I am uploading screenshot from the Maple file I made right now which is doing exactly what I want to do with Python and I'm asking in this question.

[image]

Comment: You are asking several questions here: 1. Why am I not seeing a reduction in compute time; 2. How do I know which core is operating on which value from my input array. For 1 keep in mind that spawning processes takes resources. Try having each worker do some actually complicated mathematics or just sleep, and you should be able to see that multiprocessing actually does run in parallel...

Comment: @duhaime My question is how to do the kind of parallel computation that I want. The rest of story is what I tried and failed and to make the question more clear. I added a screenshot of how I do what I couldn't do with Python, with Maple. If someone can guide me how to do the same with python, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 3):

In CPython, more or less the "standard" implementation, only *one* thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode.
So using threads to speed up computations won't work in CPython.

You could use `multiprocessing.Pool` instead. In general I would recommend using the Pool's `imap_unordered` method instead of plain `map`. The former will start yielding values as soon as they become available, while the latter returns a list after *all* calculations are done.

Getting to the core of your question, Python does not have a platform independant method specify on which CPU a process it starts will run. How so-called [processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) works is very operating system dependant as you can see on the linked page. Of course you could use `subprocess` to run one of the mentioned utility programs, or you could use `ctypes` to execute the relevant system calls directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @FlyingTeller and @quamrana who answered my the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698370/why-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-file-with-pool-map-which-causes-nothing-appearing-a), now I know how to implement the python program to do the four computations parallel such that it takes time as much as the maximum time of the four separate computations. Here is the corrected code:

```
def f(x):
    lo=0
    for i in range(x):
            lo+=i
    return(lo)
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f_parallel(x1,x2,x3,x4):
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        resulto_parallel=pool.map(f,[x1,x2,x3,x4])
    return(resulto_parallel)
import time
def f_parallel_t(x1,x2,x3,x4):
    st=time.time()
    ans=f_parallel(x1,x2,x3,x4)
    st=time.time()-st
    return(ans,st)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f_parallel_t(10**7,10**6,10**7-2,9**7))
```

And the screenshot of the result when I run it:
[image]