# What am I doing wrong in this file with pool.map which causes nothing appearing and I have to restart the shell?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-3.7

What am I missing or doing wrong in the following python file using multiprocessing? When I run it, nothing happens and I have to restart the shell!

```
def f(x):
    lo=0
    for i in range(x):
            lo+=i
    return(lo)
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f_parallel(x1,x2,x3,x4):
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        resulto_parallel=pool.map(f,[x1,x2,x3,x4])
    return(resulto_parallel)
f_parallel(1,2,3,4)
```

Here is screenshot of what happens when I run it.
[image]

And then after waiting a while I just restart the shell.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [the multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html):

> one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using `if __name__ == '__main__'`

In your case this looks like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    lo = 0
    for i in range(x):
            lo += i
    return lo

def f_parallel(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        resulto_parallel = pool.map(f, [x1, x2, x3, x4])
    return resulto_parallel 

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    print(f_parallel(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

The key point is that the spawned processes will import your python script, which, if you didn't protect the call to `f_parallel(1,2,3,4)` would result in an endless spawning of subprocesses.

**Note**: Also added a `print` so that the result of the function call will actually be put to `stdout`

Comment: Thx @bruno desthuilliers

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'module name' idiom:

```
def f(x):
    lo = 0
    for i in range(x):
            lo += i
    return lo

from multiprocessing import Pool

def f_parallel(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        return pool.map(f,[x1, x2, x3, x4])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f_parallel(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6]
```

Without the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part above, `multiprocessing` re-reads the module (executing it) and gets into an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it was a very big help. I upvoted both answers ^_^